# SQL SERVER - Using SUBSTRING

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following variable:

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(100)
SET @test =  'Prodcut A (Avegrage: 1.000)'
```

I would like to remove if the column contains begin with "(Avegrage) I am sure that I have to use SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX but not sure how. Can someone please help me?

```
SELECT @test as product, left(@test, charindex('(Avegrage', @test) - 2) AS LeftString


product                     Product Name
Prodcut A (Avegrage: 1.000) Prodcut A
```

Comment: Are you aware of typos?

Comment: Remove what from where?

Comment: What you wrote works, as long as the word you are searching for is in the @test variable. You should use an "IF charindex('(Avegrage', @test) > 0 ..." before you trim the extra junk off.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (for SQL-SERVER):

```
SELECT <something>
FROM <sometable>
WHERE <something> like 'Avegrage%'
```

this will look for the columns that have 'Avegrage' as leftmost part of the string.  The '%' is a wildcard character.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to TRIM or ELIMINATE?  If eliminating, see [@BWS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18904317/2217305).  If trimming off the beginning of the parenthesis, so that you end up with `Product A:` then ...

```
DECLARE @b NVARCHAR(100)
SET @b = 'Prodct A: (Average)'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@b,1,(CHARINDEX('(',@b)-1))
```